# What's the difference between pigment, dye and colorant?

Tags: differences, colors

For example, is 'pigment' always solid, 'dye' always liquid, and 'colorant' a general name for the both?

Comment: Keep in mind that the meaning of the terms is apt to be "defined" to a degree by the people using them.  Very likely different based on whether you're talking to a paint manufacturer, a craft materials vendor, or, say, a cake icing manufacturer.

Comment: Is this about the English language?

Comment: @medica, initially I felt that here I'd get a better answer than on the chemistry community. And Hot-Licks proved that right.

Answer (score 2):

From [Pigment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigment) on Wikipedia:

> A distinction is usually made between **a pigment, which is insoluble in
>   its vehicle** (resulting in a suspension), and **a dye, which either is
>   itself a liquid or is soluble in its vehicle** (resulting in a
>   solution). **A colorant can act as either a pigment or a dye** depending
>   on the vehicle involved. In some cases, a pigment can be manufactured
>   from a dye by precipitating a soluble dye with a metallic salt.

Comment: Please include research (especially from obvious sources like Wikipedia) _in the question_.